# What happens when Heroku SQL query times out?

Tags: sql, heroku, console, timeout

Heroku does not have built-in SQL console, so I have used the third party plugin:

```
heroku plugins:install git://github.com/ddollar/heroku-sql-console.git
```

When I run simple queries in this console, everything is Ok, but when I run complex query, the console times out.

Whet happens actually when the console displays "time out"? Does the query continue running or it is interrupted? How to increase timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have an answer what happens: the query continues running up to the end.
Heroku guys have increased sql console timeout yesterday.